# Using Redis Pubsub is it possible to subscribe to changes to a Set?

Tags: redis

Basically when my client apps start I want to retrieve a 'View of the World' using the GetMembersOfSet command but then have subsequent updates published to the clients.

So I need to subscribe to updates of a Set.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis Pub/Sub does not work directly on keys, so getting changes to a set is no different to getting changes in a regular key - when you make a change to the set, you also need to use the PUBLISH command to add a message on the appropriate channel.